# Determine div width in horizontal gallery with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, gallery

I need help. On my site [vladimirvojtela.com](http://vladimirvojtela.com/galeria.php?id=12), I have gallery with horizontally scrollbar and I have whitespace on the end, beacause of width parameter in code.

Can I remove this whitespace with some script, which determine automatic DIV width after render all images? Thanks for help!

HTML

```
<div class='photo_wrap' style='width:30685px'>


<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5627_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5635_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5644_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5654_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5674_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5680_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5684_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5693_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5731_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5737_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5738_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5751_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5774_ret_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5821_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5853_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5894_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5897_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
<img src="admin/uploads/galleries/09fa472aaefe3ab2563b97b0d5c4a325/DSC_5914_small.jpg" height="700px" style="width:auto; margin: 5px" >
</div>
```

CSS

```
.photo_wrap {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4em;
}


.photo_wrap img {
  display: inline;
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad, please include the code of your horizontal scroll-bar to make it easier for readers (HTML/CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you:

```
.photo_wrap {
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    top: 4em;     
}
```

Comment: But I need it put it into width parameter in my CSS :/ I'm newbie, can you please help me?